# Why does this && not short-circuit?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code is from the node module [templatizer](https://github.com/henrikjoreteg/templatizer).

```
if (i === 3 && node.type === "ExpressionStatement" && node.expression.callee.object.name === "buf" &&
       node.expression.arguments.length === 1 && node.expression.arguments[0].type === "Literal") {

       // save the simple string
       simpleString = node.expression.arguments[0].value;
       cnt++;
    }
```

The value of `node.type` is 'VariableDeclaration' so the logical expression is false and so `node.expression` shouldn't even be evaluated but it appears to be so...

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
>       at  /node_modules/templatizer/lib/simplifyTemplate.js:34:89
>       at Array.forEach (native)

It means the 'object' in 'callee'. `expression` and `callee` are both undefined. As soon as I step over the conditional node crashes.

**EDIT**

I think Javascript works fine and perhaps some async code is resulting in strange results form the debugger. If I put a console.log at the top of the loop it sometimes gives output that makes sense...

```
/usr/local/bin/node bin/www
count: 1
i:0
node.type: VariableDeclaration
expression: undefined
node.expression.callee: undefined

count: 2
i:1
node.type: VariableDeclaration
expression: undefined
node.expression.callee: undefined

count: 3
i:2
node.type: VariableDeclaration
expression: undefined
node.expression.callee: undefined

count: 4
i:3
node.type: ExpressionStatement
expression: [object Object]
node.expression.callee: [object Object]

count: 5
i:4
node.type: ReturnStatement
expression: undefined
node.expression.callee: undefined

count: 6
i:0
node.type: VariableDeclaration
expression: undefined
node.expression.callee: undefined

count: 7
i:1
node.type: VariableDeclaration
expression: undefined
node.expression.callee: undefined

count: 8
i:2
node.type: VariableDeclaration
expression: undefined
node.expression.callee: undefined

count: 9
i:3
node.type: ExpressionStatement
expression: [object Object]
node.expression.callee: undefined


/Users/ME/WebstormProjects/MySite/node_modules/templatizer/lib/simplifyTemplate.js:41
= 3 && node.type === "ExpressionStatement" && node.expression.callee.object.na
                                                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
    at /Users/ME/WebstormProjects/MySite/node_modules/templatizer/lib/simplifyTemplate.js:41:89
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at module.exports (/Users/ME/WebstormProjects/MySite/node_modules/templatizer/lib/simplifyTemplate.js:15:18)
    at /Users/ME/WebstormProjects/MySite/node_modules/templatizer/templatizer.js:111:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at module.exports (/Users/ME/WebstormProjects/MySite/node_modules/templatizer/templatizer.js:95:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ME/WebstormProjects/MySite/app.js:23:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

Process finished with exit code 8
```

So looks like a bug in the module.

Comment: "`node.type` is 'VariableDeclaration'" is that what your debugger told you, or just what you expect it to be?

Comment: Which file exactly are you referring to?

Comment: prove that claim to us: console log those conditional values before going into the if statement, and show us what's in them.

Comment: @lxg They're referring to [this](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/templatizer/blob/cca9b76ed982969241022024cd7cebaa5ddaf007/lib/simplifyTemplate.js#L34-L39).

Comment: Could you have a watch, breakpoint, or a local set in your debugger which is evaluating the statements that would be ignored normally?  Just a guess.

Comment: @TimSeguine Its what node tells me even when I don't run it in debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the debugger was showing values from a different part of the execution than the one that caused the crash. Surely it must be running things asynchronously somewhere. So a bug in the module. Temporary fix was to add an extra check to the conditional.

```
if (i === 3 && node.type === "ExpressionStatement" && node.expression.callee && node.expression.callee.object.name === "buf" &&
                node.expression.arguments.length === 1 && node.expression.arguments[0].type === "Literal")
```

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/templatizer/issues/70).